# IOS ld: file not found: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I used a SDK in my project, and I got this error:

```
ld: file not found: /Users/Joe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
    TWgoodCHTclzvsssbaaukcwgtenyfezlyvzvh/Build/Intermediates/TWgoodCHT.build
    /Debug-iphonesimulator/TWgoodCHT.build/Objects-normal/i386/cmdutils.o

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I try to delete "Library search paths" and "Framework search paths", but it didn't work.

Can you help me to solve this problem?
Thanks!